# How to output a 1 to many object using bookshelf js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, one-to-many, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using bookshelf and knex to connect to a PostgreSQL database. Im trying to retrieve data that has a one to many relationship. My database looks like this:

Table: athlete

```
|----------------------------|
|  id | firstname | lastname |
|----------------------------|
|  0  | john      | doe      |
|  1  | jane      | doe      |
|----------------------------|
```

Table: activity

```
|------------------------------------|
|  id | athlete_id | type | distance |
|------------------------------------|
|  0  |     1      | run  |    5     |
|  1  |     0      | walk |    7     |
|------------------------------------|
```

My bookshelf models look like this:

```
const Athlete = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'athlete',
    activities: function() {
        return this.hasMany('Activity', 'athlete_id');
    }
});

const Activity = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'activity',
    athlete: function() {
        return this.belongsTo('Athlete');
    }
});
```

Then I call `Activity.fetchAll().then(...)`

This returns

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "athlete_id": "1",
    "type": "run",
    "distance": "5",
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "athlete_id": "0",
    "type": "walk",
    "distance": "7",
  }
]
```

What I want it to return is

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "athlete": {
        "athlete_id": "1",
        "firstname": "jane",
        "lastname": "doe"
    },
    "type": "run",
    "distance": "5",
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "athlete": {
        "athlete_id": "0",
        "firstname": "john"
        "lastname": "doe"
    },
    "type": "walk",
    "distance": "7",
  }
]
```

I found this: `Activity.fetch({withRelated: 'athlete'}).then(...)` but that returns a 500 error for me with no message.

I need help trying to return a nested object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a pair of square brackets around `athlete`. That could be a possible thing causing this error.

```
Activity.fetch({withRelated: ['athlete']}).then(...)
```

**EDIT**

Hey @Derekedelaney, I tried to implement the same project and did not face any issues. You can find it [here](https://github.com/zerosand1s/StackOverflow). I got the output like this

```
[
  { id: 1,
    athlete_id: 1,
    type: 'run',
    distance: '5',
    athlete: { id: 1, firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe' } 
  },
  { id: 2,
    athlete_id: 2,
    type: 'walk',
    distance: '7',
    athlete: { id: 2, firstname: 'jane', lastname: 'doe' }
  } 
]
```

Please note that I am using Bookshelf **registry** plugin so go through that once. Let me know if you have any difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I'm still getting the same error with the `[]`

Comment: @Derekedelaney are you sure the error you are getting is because of this only?

Comment: I believe this is the reason for the error. I am able to use `fetchAll()` with no errors just not the nested objects. I just think my relationships are all messed up and bookshelf is missing something from me. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for doing all of that work. I switch to use **registry plugin** and exported my model like you did and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables use non-standard primary keys, so you must specify them using the [idAttribute](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-idAttribute) property. Simply put change your models to:

```
const Athlete = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'athlete',
    idAttribute: 'athlete_id'
    activities: function() {
        return this.hasMany('Activity', 'athlete_id');
    }
});

const Activity = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'activity',
    idAttribute: 'activity_id'
    athlete: function() {
        return this.belongsTo('Athlete');
    }
});
```

Also getting just a plain 500 HTTP status is not helpful. I recommend you to add a catch clause to your `fetch()` code, something like:

```
Activity
  .fetch({withRelated: ['athlete']})
  .then(...)
  .catch(ex => {
     log.err('Error while fetching', ex); // or at least 'console.dir(ex)'
     throw ex;
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but still no luck. Im guessing a standard primary key would be just `id` instead of `athlete_id`. Also I should clarify, I am catching the error from the `then` but that `ex` is an empty object. Lastly, I'm assuming `idAttribute: 'athele_id'` was just a typo. I added `idAttribute: 'athlete_id'`

Comment: Typo fixed. I've never seen empty exceptions (`throw undefined`?). Knex/Boolshelf exceptions may be sometimes cryptic but are always very detailed. I suggest you to double check that.

Comment: I'm using debug. The messages:
```express:router trim prefix (/v1/activities) from url /v1/activities +0ms
  express:router router /v1/activities : /v1/activities +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET / +1ms
  knex:pool INFO pool postgresql:pg:client0 - dispense() clients=1 available=2 +8ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +1ms
  knex:query select "activity".* from "activity" limit ? +6ms
  knex:bindings [ 1 ] +0ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +6ms
  knex:pool INFO pool postgresql:pg:client0 - dispense() clients=0 available=2 +0ms```

Comment: Not the best way to share this...
edit: url-- https://gist.github.com/derekedelaney/058b5f4da8f6cc9c06d3ed081c768a8a